# JPA OneToMany Relationship - foreignkey is not set

Tags: hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

I send data to server with ajax post

```
  var obj = {
    'sub': 'this is a test.'
    ,'userName': 'dbdyd'
    ,'saveDate': new Date()
    ,'comments': [
       {'comment':'1a', 'saveDate2': new Date(), 'seq2': null}
       ,{'comment':'2b', 'saveDate2': new Date(), 'seq2': null}
    ]
  };


  $.ajax({
    url: '/cp/RestApi/Posts',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj)
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

I met server error.
foreignKey is not set to Comments table.

```
  INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
  Posts [seq=null, sub=this is a test., userName=dbdyd, saveDate=Sun Mar 13 09:05:46 KST 2016
, comments=[Comments [seq2=null, comment=2b, saveDate2=Sun Mar 13 09:05:46 KST 2016, posts=null], Comments [seq2=null, comment=1a, saveDate2=Sun Mar 13 09:05:46 KST 2016, posts=null]]]
Hibernate: insert into onnuricp.posts (save_date, sub, user_name) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into onnuricp.comments (comment, seq, save_date2) values (?, ?, ?)
09:05:47.315 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'seq' cannot be null
Mar 13, 2016 9:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

database schema

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '게시판번호',
  `sub` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '제목',
  `user_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '작성자',
  `save_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '입력일자',
  PRIMARY KEY (`seq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='게시판'



CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `seq2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '댓글번호',
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '내용',
  `save_date2` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '작성일자',
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '게시판번호',
  PRIMARY KEY (`seq2`),
  KEY `FK_posts_TO_comments` (`seq`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_posts_TO_comments` FOREIGN KEY (`seq`) REFERENCES `posts` (`seq`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='댓글'
;
```

I have some problem with spring data jpa.
@OneToMany relationship seems to be wrong but I don't know about it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Posts {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "seq")
  private Integer seq;

  @Column(name = "sub", nullable = true)
  private String sub;

  @Column(name = "user_name")
  private String userName;

  @Column(name = "save_date", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date saveDate;

  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "posts", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Comments> comments;

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comments implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "seq2")
  private Integer seq2;

  @Column(name = "comment", nullable = false)
  private String comment;

  @Column(name = "save_date2", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date saveDate2;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "seq", referencedColumnName="seq", nullable = false)
  private Posts posts;

}
```

save the object (Posts and Comments).
and service implements like this.

```
Posts entity = new Post();
Posts savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
```

please help me out with JPA Relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@OneToMany` mapping looks correct. But you don't need to specify `referencedColumnName = "seq"` just use

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "seq", nullable = false)
private Posts posts;
```

Don't use plural for `Comments` and `Posts`. Just `Comment`, `Post`.

You can save `Comments` using `Posts`

```
Posts post = new Posts();
post.setComments(new HashSet<Comments>());

Comments comment = new Comments();
comment.setPosts(post);
post.getComments().add(comment);

save(post);
```

If you already have a `post` in the database.  You can add a `comment` by this way

```
Comments comment = new Comments();
comment.setPosts(post);

save(comment);
```

Comment: thans to @v.ladynev very much for your polite answer!! ~~.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problems and ran into another problems.
so, I add some solution to this post.

first, I fixed it that foreign key is not set to Comments object.
I have to add method [**addComments(Comments co)**] to Posts class.
if I have array Comments Object, I have to add Object Method that it implements to add to collection. Nothing to add another things.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts", catalog = "onnuricp")
public class Posts {

  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "posts", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Comments> comments;

  public Posts() {
    comments = new HashSet<Comments>();
  }

  public void addComments(Comments co) {
    co.setPosts(this);
    comments.add(co);
  }

}
```

Second, I ran into a problem about **Jackson databind error**.
add some code to fix it.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "seq2")

public class CommentsDto implements Serializable {

  getter .. ;
  setter .. ;

}


@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "seq")

public class PostsDto implements Serializable {

  getter .. ;
  setter .. ;
}
```